# Python unittest directory: correct way to setup unit-test only dependencies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a python package with the following directory structure:

```
ProjectName
  > setup.py
  > README.txt
  > PackageName
     >> ...<various .py files>...
  > tests
     >> settings
        >>> __init__.py
        >>> unit_test_utils1.py
        >>> unit_test_utils2.py
     >> __init__.py
     >> test1.py
     >> test2.py
```

I have some utility functions inside `settings/unit_test_utils*.py` only useful for setting up environment in my unit tests.  What is the correct way to structure my project / imports so that these functions are useable in my unit test?

Inside `test1.py` I have the following:

```
import unittest

import sys
sys.path.append("..")
import PackageName

## option 1
from .settings import unit_test_utils1
from .settings import unit_test_utils2

## option 2
from settings import unit_test_utils1
from settings import unit_test_utils2


## is there a better way to handle this?
```

I use `sys.path.append("..")` which is kind of a hacky way for my unit tests to import `PackageName` and then I have two different options for importing the utilities into my tests.

If I opt for option 1, if my current directory is `ProjectName/` I can run my unit tests using `python -m unittest tests.test1` but if my working directory is `ProjectName/tests` then doing `python -m unittest test1` will give me a `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Similarly if I opt for option 2, if my current directory is `ProjectName/test` then running `python -m unittest test1` works fine but if my current directory is `ProjectName/` using `python -m unittest tests.test1` will give an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'`.

What's a better way to setup my directory and import structure to allow importing helper utilities into my unit tests?  Having unit tests error out because of running them from a different directory seems like a bad solution overall and I'm already using other hacks to be able to import the package.

Answer (score 0):

One way and the way I would use:

- remove the `sys.path.append` line.
- Keep your cwd as `~/ProjectName/`
- change the imports in `test1.py` to:

```py
import unittest
import PackageName
from tests.settings import unit_test_utils1
from tests.settings import unit_test_utils2
```